# PFObject Subclassing: @NSManaged [UIInt8] "Property cannot be marked @NSManaged

Tags: parse-platform

Trying to subclass PFObject with an array of UInt8 i.e.

```
class UserDetailID : PFObject, PFSubclassing
{
    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
            dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "UserDetailID"
    }

    @NSManaged var tmpArray : [[UInt8]]  
}
```

Xcode is complaining "Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C"

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Show the rest of your subclass declaration. Also, try adding `@objc(MySubclass)` on the line before `class MySubclass: NSManagedObject {`

Comment: Thanks ... Code updated above.

Comment: Have you tried using the Swift type `Int` instead of `UInt8`? In other words, `@NSManaged var tmpArray : [[Int]]`

Comment: Yes.. but Int = Int32.  this then makes the object larger than the parse 128kB limit

Comment: Int32 means 32-bit, signed binary integer. The Parse object limit is 128KB, which means 1.024*10^6 bits. 1024000 bits > 32 bits. The 128KB limit is well beyond what you need.

Comment: it is a nested array with 25 blocks with a size of 256.   parse rejects during save .. otherwise would have use [Int]

Comment: Sounds like it's time to restructure your data. You could create another class for containing the data and then reference it from User. You shouldn't be using Parse to store nested arrays